# How can I render something made in blender in maxwell

Tags: rendering, export, external-applications

Is it possible to make a whole scene in blender and after it's all done to just import it somehow in maxwell and render it there?

Comment: I don't know much about Mawell, so I don't know the requirements that Maxwell has for files it imports, but assuming that you can fined the specifications that Maxwell expects, you should theoretically be  able to do what you  want. This site, though, is dedicated to Blender, and while we could help with details  of the modeling the rest of the question is not Blender related, and I'm  voting to  close is as out of scope.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/bmaxwell/